# printing all the "articles" related to the content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

my content type, plan to have one or more 'articles'.

the following php code, I can get them all:

```
<?php print render($content['field_articolo_di_riferimento']);?>
```

and I get the following result:

[image]

I would like to remove the title in bold above the links of the articles, so I tried:

```
<?php 
  $lenght = count($field_articolo_di_riferimento);

  for($i=0; $i<lenght; $i++){
  print render($content['field_articolo_di_riferimento'][$i]);
}
?>
```

but does not work. It is probably the wrong way I use to count the length of the array.

this is the structure of my content type:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, why don't you go to `Manage display` of your content type. `?q=admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display`

And next to your field `Articolo di Riferimento` for the `Label` value choose `<Hidden>`. That should hide the label from the node display.

This is much similar. Besides the code you use **will never** affect the label.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.